# Installing upgrade to Windows Service with no downtime

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need make upgrade code for my Windows service. The requirement is the service cannot be stopped during upgrade. So what I'm trying to achieve is actually running both versions of the service for a short period of time, then uninstall the older version.

Of course I know I cannot install more than one service with the same name. So, in second installation I change name to `MyService_1.1.0.0`. It's perfectly good name, and the service installs with no problem but... only if `MyService` is not installed. When I try to install both I got an error in Service Installer, that the second one is not installed.

The most evil part is there is no exception thrown. Debugger attached to service process doesn't help. There's nothing in the logs. The installer just silently refuse to install the second service and I have no idea where to go from here.

What do both services have in common beside identical source code? They have different names, different assembly versions, different paths, but the same descriptions, the same event log names.

I'll try to change the event log name in second service, maybe it would help, but is it a way of finding out WHY service installation fails? It's bugging me for years - there's never an actual exception to be found. It's always a fake exception, something "Error - service is not installed, because it's not installed".

The second question is: is there a better way to ensure the service is on during upgrade? Well, it seems like the requirement is impossible to meet, but from the other hand - if I made a plain exe, not a service, which would temporarily take over the old service operation during upgrade process, it just might work. Then I would uninstall the old version, install the new one and exit the helper process. It seems a little bit complicated (btw, the service operation involve using a low level system driver), but maybe it would be cleaner than trying to run both versions at the same time.

Comment: I guess there is some string that you missed to change to the new name. Could that be the case? Clearly, the two services are sharing *something*.

Comment: Could you host the app in IIS? That way zero downtime deployments are easier using the blue green model.

Comment: No, the name is changed, it's outputted in installer error. I got "Creating EventLog source MyService_1.1.0.0..." and then "An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of ServiceInstaller." Of course exception is that service is not installed. No reason given.

Comment: It cannot be hosted in IIS. It performs low level network operations using (custom) system driver. IIS should not allow this due to security reasons. It really shouldn't allow this ;) Because if it allowed to run usafe code, it would be too easy to take it down with software bugs or malicious code.

Comment: Does your service open any resources in an exclusive way (network port or disk file etc) that would prevent two instances running simultaneously?

Comment: IIS allows any code at all to run. Not sure it's the better choice, though. You have less control over process lifetimes.

Comment: The only resource which seems to be shared is event log. I even start a new network driver for the new service. It could fail, but it doesn't. Those drivers can operate side by side. I forgot to mention - it's a named log, not default application log. I think it could be the case. Failure to write an entry to event log cause service installer to fail silently, since it can't log actual error message. It leads to the second part of the question, maybe it's a better way than 2 services at the same time... Because 2 logs, temporary names, duplicated drivers, it doesn't look good.